# Assembly.GetTypes() slow in post build event but fast when debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

In one of our post build events we need to run a small application which calls Assembly.GetTypes() for some of our assemblies.

The code looks like this (simplified):

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fis.FullName);
var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
...
```

When debugging this code, GetTypes() only needs some milliseconds for every assembly. But when running it as an post build event it needs about one minute for a specific assembly (but only on my PC, it works properly on the PCs of my colleagues).

Do you have any ideas what could cause this? (Assembly.Load() / LoadFrom() / LoadFile() makes no difference)

Thank you & best regards,
Maggi

Comment: Are you positivley sure its the assemnly loading that is making the post build event take time? How did you come onto that conclusion?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is caused by Assembly.GetTypes(). Using the profiler YourKit I was able to see that it is stuck in Assembly.GetTypes(). Afterwards I extended the logging (including timestamps) of the application to confirm this (successfully).

Comment: I'm having similar issues with a C++CLI project running Metagen as a post build task and getting stuck for over10 minutes in Module.GetTypes().